# Computing a ratio involving Haar random unitaries

Tags: quantum-state, probability, haar-distribution

Consider an $n$-qubit Haar random unitary $U$.

I am trying to compute the expression

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{\text{Tr}\left(|0^n\rangle \langle 0^n | ~U\rho U^*\right)}{\text{Tr}\left(\mathbb{I} \otimes |0^{n-1}\rangle \langle 0^{n-1} | ~U\rho U^*\right)} \right],
\end{equation}

where $\rho$ is an arbitrary $n$-qubit quantum state, the expectation is taken over the choice of $U$ and $\mathbb{I}$ is a $2 \times 2$ identity operator.

Note that each of the numerator and denominator can individually be computed in expectation, but I am not sure how to manipulate the ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler way.

Since the Haar measure is left and right invariant, we are free to pull out a unitary to the left or right of $U$ and the expectation is left invariant.

In particular, let $U \mapsto (V \otimes \mathbb{I}_{2^{n-1}})U$,  where $V$ is some   2-qubit unitary, and  $\mathbb{I}_{2^{n-1}}$ the identity on the rest of the $n-1$ qubits. Your desired quantity can thus equivalently be written as

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_U\left[ \frac{\text{Tr}_{1,2,\cdots,n}\left(|0^n\rangle \langle 0^n | ~ (V \otimes \mathbb{I}_{2^{n-1}}) U\rho U^\dagger(V^\dagger \otimes \mathbb{I}_{2^{n-1}}) \right)}{\text{Tr}_{1,2,\cdots,n} \left(\mathbb{I} \otimes |0^{n-1}\rangle \langle 0^{n-1} | ~U\rho U^\dagger \right)} \right].
\end{equation}
Note the pleasing fact that $V$ appears in the numerator only, not in the denominator. I have also added   subscripts in the traces, simply as book-keeping, in order to keep track of which spaces the trace is over: in both the numerator and denominator they are over qubits $1,2,\cdots,n$, which seems like redundant notation. But bear with me...

Since we get the same value for any choice of $V$, let's average over different instances of $V$, where $V$ is drawn uniformly over the single qubit unitary group. In other words, we Haar average $V$. Thus your desired value can be equivalently expressed
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_U\mathbb{E}_V\left[ \frac{\text{Tr}_{1,2,\cdots,n}\left(|0^n\rangle \langle 0^n | ~ (V \otimes \mathbb{I}_{2^{n-1}}) U\rho U^\dagger(V^\dagger \otimes \mathbb{I}_{2^{n-1}}) \right)}{\text{Tr}_{1,2,\cdots,n} \left(\mathbb{I} \otimes |0^{n-1}\rangle \langle 0^{n-1} | ~U\rho U^\dagger \right)} \right].
\end{equation}
Now,  the $V$-averaging we **can** do explicitly (using $\mathbb{E}_V[ V O V^\dagger] = \text{Tr}(O) \frac{\mathbb{I}}{2}$). This gives
\begin{align}
& \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}_U \left[ \frac{\text{Tr}_{1,2,\cdots,n}\left(|0^n\rangle \langle 0^n | \mathbb{I} \otimes \text{Tr}_1[ U\rho U^\dagger]) \right)}{\text{Tr}_{1,2,\cdots,n}\left(\mathbb{I} \otimes |0^{n-1}\rangle \langle 0^{n-1} | ~U\rho U^\dagger \right)} \right] = \\
&\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}_U \left[ \frac{\text{Tr}_{2,\cdots,n}\left(|0^{n-1}\rangle \langle 0^{n-1} |\text{Tr}_1[ U\rho U^\dagger]) \right)}{\text{Tr}_{1,2,\cdots,n}\left(\mathbb{I} \otimes |0^{n-1}\rangle \langle 0^{n-1} | ~U\rho U^\dagger \right)} \right] = \\
&\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}_U \left[ \frac{\text{Tr}_{2,\cdots,n}\left(|0^{n-1}\rangle \langle 0^{n-1} |\text{Tr}_1[ U\rho U^\dagger]) \right)}{\text{Tr}_{2,\cdots,n}\left(|0^{n-1}\rangle \langle 0^{n-1} |\text{Tr}_1[ U\rho U^\dagger]) \right)} \right] = \\
& \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}_U[1] = \nonumber \\
& \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Since the numerator and the denominator are (apparently) not independent, I'm not convinced that their expectation can be computed separately.

First of all, note that:
$$\DeclareMathOperator{Tr}{Tr}\begin{align}\Tr\left(\mathbb{I} \otimes \left|0^{n-1}\middle\rangle\middle\langle 0^{n-1}\right|U\rho U^\dagger\right)&=\Tr\left(\left|0^n\middle\rangle\middle\langle0^n\right|U\rho U^\dagger + \left|1\middle\rangle\middle|0^{n-1}\middle\rangle\middle\langle1|\middle\langle0^{n-1}\right|U\rho U^\dagger\right)\\&=\Tr\left(\left|0^n\middle\rangle\middle\langle0^n\right|U\rho U^\dagger\right) + \Tr\left(\left|1\middle\rangle\middle|0^{n-1}\middle\rangle\middle\langle1|\middle\langle0^{n-1}\right|U\rho U^\dagger\right)\end{align}$$
Furthermore, note that:
$$\Tr\left(\left|0^{n}\middle\rangle\middle\langle 0^{n}\right|U\rho U^\dagger\right)=a_{0,0}$$
and :
$$\Tr\left(\left|1\middle\rangle\middle|0^{n-1}\middle\rangle\middle\langle1|\middle\langle0^{n-1}\right|U\rho U^\dagger\right)=a_{2^{n-1},2^{n-1}}$$
when denoting:
$$U\rho U^\dagger=\begin{pmatrix}a_{0,0}&\cdots&a_{0, 2^{n}-1\\}\\\vdots & \ddots&\vdots\\a_{2^n-1,0}&\cdots&a_{2^n-1,2^n-1}\end{pmatrix}$$
Thus:
$$\frac{\Tr\left(\left|0^{n}\middle\rangle\middle\langle 0^{n}\right|U\rho U^\dagger\right)}{\Tr\left(\mathbb{I} \otimes \left|0^{n-1}\middle\rangle\middle\langle 0^{n-1}\right|U\rho U^\dagger\right)}=\frac{a_{0,0}}{a_{0,0}+a_{2^{n-1},2^{n-1}}}$$
For now, suppose $\rho$ is pure. Thus, it can be written as $V|0\rangle$ without loss of generality. Since $UV$ is Haar-random for a Haar-random $U$, without loss of generality, we can assume that $\rho=|0\rangle\langle0|$. $a_{0,0}$ and $a_{2^{n-1},2^{n-1}}$ are then the probabilities of measuring the states $|0\rangle$ and $\left|2^{n-1}\right\rangle$ respectively. We know that for a Haar-random state, its coefficients are drawn independtly from a complex Gaussian and then normalized. That is, we can write $a_{0,0}$ as $\frac{A_{0,0}^2+B_{0,0}^2}{M^2}$ and $a_{2^{n-1},2^{n-1}}$ as $\frac{A_{2^{n-1},2^{n-1}}^2+B_{2^{n-1},2^{n-1}}^2}{M^2}$, with $A_{i,i}$ and $B_{i,i}$ being independelty drawn from $\mathcal{N}(0;1)$. The expectation we want to compute is then:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\frac{A_{0,0}^2+B_{0,0}^2}{M^2}}{\frac{A_{0,0}^2+B_{0,0}^2}{M^2}+\frac{A_{2^{n-1},2^{n-1}}^2+B_{2^{n-1},2^{n-1}}^2}{M^2}}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{A_{0,0}^2+B_{0,0}^2}{A_{0,0}^2+B_{0,0}^2+A_{2^{n-1},2^{n-1}}^2+B_{2^{n-1},2^{n-1}}^2}\right]$$
The interesting point here is that, contrarily to $a_{0,0}$ and $a_{2^{n-1},2^{n-1}}$, $A_{0,0}^2+B_{0,0}^2$ and $A_{2^{n-1},2^{n-1}}^2+B_{2^{n-1},2^{n-1}}^2$ are i.i.d. As such, we have:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{A_{0,0}^2+B_{0,0}^2}{A_{0,0}^2+B_{0,0}^2+A_{2^{n-1},2^{n-1}}^2+B_{2^{n-1},2^{n-1}}^2}\right]=\frac12.$$

Indeed, for $X$ and $Y$ being i.i.d., the following holds:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{Y}{X+Y}\right]$$
but one also has that:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{Y}{X+Y}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X+Y}{X+Y}\right]=1$$
Thus, if $\rho$ is pure, this expectation equals $\frac12$. Suppose now that $\rho$ can be written as:
$$\rho=\sum_kp_k\rho_k$$
with $\rho_k$ being pure for every $k$ and the $p_k$ summing to $1$. The quantity one wishes to take the expectation of is:
$$\frac{\sum\limits_kp_ka_{0,0,k}}{\sum\limits_kp_ka_{0,0,k}+\sum\limits_kp_ka_{2^{n-1},2^{n-1},k}}$$
Using the same argument as before, these two random variables are i.i.d. Thus, the expectation value is still $\frac12$ in this case.

Comment: Thanks! One follow-up question: how general is the fact that $a_{0,0}$ and $a_{2^{n-1},2^{n-1}}$ are i.i.d? Is it true only for Haar random states or is it also true for $k$-designs?

Comment: @BlackHat18 I think this is only true for Haar-random states. For instance, if I'm not mistaken, the Clifford group is a $2$-design, but $U|0\rangle$ for $U$ being sampled uniformly from the Clifford group doesn't yield a vector whose amplitudes are drawn from a complex Gaussian.

Comment: how did you go from the expectation value of the ration to the ratio of the exp values? I mean the step $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{y} }]=\frac{1}{1+\frac{\mathbb{E}[x]}{\mathbb{E}[y]}}$

Comment: @glS My reasoning was potentially flawed, but in fact you can simply use the fact that if $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d., then $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right]=\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{\mathbb{E}[X+Y]}=\frac12$. I've corrected it.

Comment: @TristanNemoz I'm still not seeing it tbh. Assuming for simplicity a discrete prob distribution, and IID random variables, LHS is $\sum_{x,y} p_x p_y \frac{x}{x+y}$ while RHS is $\frac{\sum_x p_x x}{\sum_x p_x x+\sum_y p_y y}$. I don't see how these are equal in general. The IID assumption tells you $\mathbb{E}[f(X)g(Y)]=\mathbb{E}[f(X)]\mathbb{E}[g(Y)]$, but this is a bit more than that no?

Comment: @glS Not a great proof, but I think this works: $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{Y}{X+Y}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X+Y}{X+Y}\right]=1$. Now since $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d., $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{Y}{X+Y}\right]$ (this can be seen by directly writing down the integrals), thus $2\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right]=1$, hence $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X}{X+Y}\right]=\frac12$. Now note that $\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{\mathbb{E}[X+Y]}=\frac12$ by linearity and you get the result.

Comment: @glS Though, the fact that the proof directly shows that this is equal to $\frac12$ without using the second equality is misleading in my post, so I've edited it and added the proof.

Comment: @TristanNemoz Yes, Clifford groups are a 2-design and the amplitudes aren’t a complex Gaussian, but regardless, can we at least say that the coefficients are independent and identically distributed?

Comment: @BlackHat18 Hm, I'm not sure about it, I would advise for asking this question in a new post directly!

Comment: @BlackHat18 I've thought about it a bit more and have corrected  the part about $a_{0,0}$ and $a_{2^{n-1},2^{n-1}}$ being i.i.d. Indeed, I'm not sure they are i.i.d. since they are normalized, which is done w.r.t. their values. Fortunately here, it doesn't matter as the normalisation constant goes away.

Comment: @TristanNemoz Even though the normalisation goes away, I’m still not sure they are independent, or even identically distributed. This is because to pick a Haar random unitary, first we sample from iid Gaussians, then we normalise the rows, and then we apply a Gram Schmidt process to make the rows orthogonal. I don’t think this last step preserves the identical distribution property (or independence.)

Comment: If the entries of the unitary are not identically distributed, then how can entries of the state be identically distributed?

Comment: @BlackHat18 You're right about this. However, we're not talking about the entries of a Haar-random unitary here, but about those of a Haar-random state. This is equivalent to considering the first column of the Haar-random unitary only, which is left unchanged by the Gramm-Schmidt process for instance. Another way to see it is to consider a Haar-random state $|\psi\rangle$ and $\sigma=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$. The normalization happens in sampling $|\psi\rangle$, and no Gramm-Schmidt process is involved.